# Are there expiration dates on music added to my Apple Music collection?

Tags: itunes, windows, apple-music

I add some songs or albums to my collection/library.

Sometimes, in a few months, they seem to be automatically removed and I need to re-add them.

The songs and albums are still available, not like if they were removed by the artists.

Is there some time limit or way to trace what’s happening here?

**Edit** :

I'm mainly use iTunes on PC to manage my collection/library (and listen on my iPhone when on the go)

I add music by clicking the "+" button or the "+Add" button.

I mostly add full albums.

Comment: What [setting do you have for adding a track](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/236393/5472)? You might also want to let us know which application you use to add the music. Web, iOS, iPadOS, macOS, android? https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/music-web/apdm4cb7b117/web

Comment: Great -  thanks max. On the Mac, the preference to not add the song to your library would explain things. Let’s see what people that use the windows client have to say, as well..